# Can we deviate a bullet from its target? Did anybody try this?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

Can we deviate a bullet from its target? Means by applying any strong field at the target? Is there any technique so far like this!

Comment: What do you mean by "strong field"? A magnetic field? An electric field?

Comment: Crossed fields:The Hall effect ... in case of electrons...but a bullet???

Comment: Yes, we call that body armor. Every piece of solid matter is a quantum field. Armor is a quantum field with a very special structure that is good at stopping bullets.

Comment: @user52076: If you are really interested to know about deviating a bullet or to become superman, read Michio Kaku's Physics of Impossible.

Comment: What's the bullet made of?  How massive? What speed?  Deviate how much?

Comment: If this is so you can figure out ways of protecting yourself, it is honestly a much better idea to avoid situations where you have to worry about bullets flying in your direction

Comment: @CuriousOne: Don't you mean every piece of solid matter is an excitation of a quantum field, rather than a quantum field itself? :)

Comment: @JamalS: You are absolutely right, that's what I meant to say. Excuse my language. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another completely different answer with a different technology. It is the use of spaced charged armour to disrupt the jet of molten metal from a shaped charge. The idea is that as the metal jet bridges the two sheets of armour is completes a short circuit as the armour is connected to a high energy capacitor. The resulting current flow disrupts the jet.

[Electric Reactive Armour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_armour#Electric_reactive_armour)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Mythbusters had an episode where they try to deflect a bullet shot just above some high strength Neodymium magnets. You can probably find it on YouTube. The deflection due to induced current was negligible.

Comment: How magnetic are bullets?

Comment: They are not magnetic but traversing a magnetic field induces electrical currents in the metal (lead, or copper jacket)  that creates a magnetic field of their own.