# Can we create a large safe electromagnet field in schools to prevent mass shooting?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I am not a physicist, so this may be a stupid question.  Gun control is hard in U.S.  In a fantasy world, I am wondering if it is possible to create a large electromagnet field in school hallways or classrooms, so that metals like Gun can be attracted to ground or wall once the field is activated, and such a field would not be harmful to human beings for a short amount of time window say a few minutes.

Comment: Probably related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139116/25301

Comment: What about everything else made of magnetic material? Guns aren't the only things that pose hazards. In addition it would have to be significantly powerful to 'attract' a gun out of the possession of a shooter. Lastly, just letting you know as somebody who has a few guns themselves, many guns nowadays are made out of polymers and non-ferrous metals. The amount of metal components by mass in some of these newer guns is minuscule. Interesting question, but perhaps not as thorough as this website demands.

Comment: ok, thanks all for your knowledge sharing.  sounds like this is not a feasible solution at all, too bad.  we human being can invent technology to kill but can't find a technology to prevent that

Answer (score 3):

To produce a magnetic field strong enough to pull a gun out of a shooter's grip in a single school corridor would require a truly enormous magnet structure that extended perhaps ten feet underground and ten feet above the top of the corridor, weighing hundreds of tons, and it would produce a field only about ten feet across. Therefore, to protect an entire school with these would require hundreds of such magnets.

The electrical power needed to turn all those magnets on at once would be momentarily similar to the electrical power draw of a small city- unless superconducting magnets were used, in which case each would require a huge cryogenic refrigeration system running 24-7.

Finally, making the gun out of aluminum or plastic instead of steel would render these magnets useless.

Comment: Not to mention dental retainers...

Comment: There are many images of the damage done around MRI machines when somebody carelessly brings a magnetic material into the room - chairs, gas cylinders, fridges, surgical knives, toolboxes... having big magnets around like this might actually provide new ways of harming people.

Comment: @anderssandberg, ja ja, det er sant.